# Which approach is better to search a keyword on nested array or normal arrays?

Tags: sql, arrays, database, algorithm

I have different tables `School, Student, Course` on my `SQL` database. I want to design a search algorithm which should make user to search by any of those table names (`School, Student, Course`) and bring only their name list very fast. But that search keyword can be anything - either school name, student name or course name.

- `School` is model and has: name, location.
- `Student` is model and has student number, name, schoolid, courseid.
- `Course` is model and has course name, courseid.

School name, student name or course name can be search for in all data. And result should bring only that model.
For example if I search for (John = student name), it should bring me all students named John only with student model values (object). Or course name (mathematics) also can be another example and it should only bring its properties as object too.

I came up with 2 different approaches:

1. I can create nested object array like School -> Student -> Course (includes each other on each object) and name will be searched on these nested arrays. I think this is not good because in anyway all those big and large arrays will be visited (Doesn't matter we checked for school name or not).
2. Second one I think makes more sense. Instead of making them nested I can search that keyword on each table one by one. First school then student then course (If its school then will be much easier than nested one even).

If you have a better approach please share it with me.

Comment: Could you add an example of your structure and explain what do you mean by _"search by table name bring only their name list"_ and what you expect as search result?

Comment: I did you can see

Comment: What would be the expected result if the student "maria" follows the course 'implimetations of mariadb" in the school "maria garden academy"?

Comment: Expect result would be Maria(name) and course id to reach what course she took and schoolid .As I explained above the values of models

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's still unclear, where you want to "design your search algorithm" and get your result "objects"! Since it's a question asked with `SQL` tag, I'd say that you should simply do 3 simple `select` queries on all tables for each search term. Any joins would mix the schemas and you'll have to distinguish results afterwards.

You're probably talking about some oop language with a database connectivity interface which does the job of queries and converting results into objects. In this case you would simply combine the result of each separate query with the features of language to get your objects.